# MongoDB find calls twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

On init of my application i start function with settings.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const monk = require('monk');
const db = monk(config.mdbConnect);
var TGusers = db.get('TG-users');
...
...
TGusers.find({'cron.status': true}, {chatid:1, cron: 1})
  .then((users) => {
    console.log('twise');
    for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){
      cronbox[users[i]] = {};
      cronbox[users[i]].reminder = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(chatid){
        console.log('chatid = '+ chatid);
        tg.api.sendMessage(chatid, ' Nuclear launch detected! / ' +chatid,
          {'parse_mode': 'Markdown'}
        );
      }.bind(null, users[i].chatid));
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    if(err) saveerr(err);
  }).then(() => db.close())
```

And this Monk find finction fired twice. I got two "twice" in my console, and .. looks like two cron tasks... What I did wrong?

Comment: Are you sure to launch the application just once ? Add `process.pid` to your log to be sure.

Comment: I maked just easy `console.log('single')` before `TGusers.find` and it run single time.